# Binary search a guessing number

Tags: c#

My lecturer asked us to write a loop to ask the user to guess a random number in 1-100. When I tested the program, I found the fastest way to get the correct number is always guessing the middle number. Then I was told that this  way is called binary search algorithm. So I'm thinking of writing another program to let the computer to guess the random number using binary search. Well, my program get the correct number, but there is a bug really bothers me which is that the count of guessing is 1 bigger. Can anyone give me a hint?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int start = 0;
        int end = 100;
        Random myRandom = new Random(); 
        int computer = myRandom.Next(start, end);
        int count = 1;
        int guess;
        guess = (end - start) / 2 + start;
        Console.WriteLine("Computer number: {0}, your guess is: {1}", computer, guess);
        Console.WriteLine("Count {0}", count);
        while (guess != computer)
        {
            guess = (end - start) / 2 + start;
            if (guess > computer)
            {
                end = guess;
                Console.WriteLine("Your guess is too high, next guess: {0}", guess);
            }
            else
            {
                start = guess;
                Console.WriteLine("Your guess is too low, guess again: {0}", guess);
            }
            count = count + 1;
            Console.WriteLine("Count {0}", count);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("You got it. The number is {0}. It took you {1} guesses.", computer, count);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

This is the result, count should be 7 not 8

> Computer number: 77, your guess is: 50
>   Count 1
>   Your guess is too low, guess again: 50
>   Count 2
>   Your guess is too low, guess again: 75
>   Count 3
>   Your guess is too high, next guess: 87
>   Count 4
>   Your guess is too high, next guess: 81
>   Count 5
>   Your guess is too high, next guess: 78
>   Count 6
>   Your guess is too low, guess again: 76
>   Count 7
>   Your guess is too low, guess again: 77
>   Count 8
>   You got it. The number is 77. It took you 8 guesses.

Comment: I just realized that I should guess the number inside "if" and "else" not outside, so problem solved. Thank you guys.

Comment: That's not the problem.  See my answer, you are guessing the same number twice to start.

Answer (score 2):

declaring

```
int count = 0;
```

instead of

```
int count = 1;
```

should solve the problem.

EDİT:

yea, you're right. If you move some of the code and delete some it will become like this

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int start = 0;
    int end = 100;
    Random myRandom = new Random();
    int computer = myRandom.Next(start, end);
    int count = 0;
    int guess;

    while (true)
    {
        guess = (end - start) / 2 + start;
        count = count + 1;
        Console.WriteLine("Count {0}", count);
        if (guess > computer)
        {
            end = guess;
            Console.WriteLine("Your guess is too high, next guess: {0}", guess);
        }
        else if (guess < computer)
        {
            start = guess;
            Console.WriteLine("Your guess is too low, guess again: {0}", guess);
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine("You got it. The number is {0}. It took you {1} guesses.", computer, count);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

you don't have to write the code twice this way(as you had before the while and in the while)

Comment: No it won't... not close.  Read the program.

Comment: No, if you guess at the first time (_computer = 50_) then you will get the message: "It took you 0 guesses"

Comment: ah now you added an if statement

Comment: so where is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You are writing the following duplicate loc outside the while loop:

```
guess = (end - start) / 2 + start;
Console.WriteLine("Computer number: {0}, your guess is: {1}", computer, guess);
Console.WriteLine("Count {0}", count);

while(guess != computer)
```

Here's the solution:

1. You should initialize your guess to a value that does not fall between `0` and `100` i.e, `guess = 999` so that it enters the loop.
2. You should remove the duplicate lines of code above the while.
3. Initialize your `count` to `0`.

Here's the code for your reference:

```
int start = 0;
int end = 100;
Random myRandom = new Random();
int computer = myRandom.Next(start, end);
int count = 0;
int guess = 999;

while (guess != computer)
{
    guess = (end - start) / 2 + start;
    if (guess > computer)
    {
        end = guess;
        Console.WriteLine("Your guess is too high, next guess: {0}", guess);
    }
    else
    {
        start = guess;
        Console.WriteLine("Your guess is too low, guess again: {0}", guess);
    }
    count = count + 1;
    Console.WriteLine("Count {0}", count);
}
Console.WriteLine("You got it. The number is {0}. It took you {1} guesses.", computer, count);
Console.ReadKey();
```

Plus duplicating code is not a good coding practice.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think that `do` is more accurate here than `while`. My version of your program:

```
int start = 0;
int end = 100;
Random myRandom = new Random();
int computer = myRandom.Next(start, end);
int count = 0;
int guess;
Console.WriteLine("Computer number: {0}", computer);
do {
    count++;
    Console.WriteLine("Count {0}", count);
    guess = (end - start) / 2 + start;
    if (guess > computer) {
        end = guess;
        Console.WriteLine("Your guess is too high, your guess: {0}", guess);
    }
    else if (guess < computer) {
        start = guess;
        Console.WriteLine("Your guess is too low, your again: {0}", guess);
    }
}
while (guess != computer);

Console.WriteLine("You got it. The number is {0}. It took you {1} guesses.", computer, count);
Console.ReadKey();
```

And the output is something like this:

[image: output]

Comment: you also added another if statement... the do vs while had little to do with it. (pun intended)

Comment: @Hogan This line: `guess = (end - start) / 2 + start;` and this `Console.WriteLine("Count {0}", count);` occurred twice. The statement "do" is better than "while" in this context.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that after your first guess (outside the loop) you are not updating `start` or `end`, so it's guessing the same thing again.

Comment: Yes, the same guess is made again, but there is one more problem - the count is still 1, it needs to be changed to 0 for it to show the right value..

Comment: @frostedcoder That depends on how you fix it.  If you fix it by updating the start or end after the initial guess, then no, the count should be 1.

Comment: I agree that it depends on how you fix it, but I am not exactly sure what you mean by updating start and end after initial guess. Can you please provide a code sample? Thanks.

Comment: @frostedcoder No.  There is a guess at the beginning, and another one inside the loop.  There is an update to start/end inside the loop, but not one after the initial guess.

Answer (score -1):

Add in a check before output and increment:

```
while (guess != computer)
{
    guess = (end - start) / 2 + start;
    if (guess != computer)
    {
        if (guess > computer)
        {
            end = guess;
            Console.WriteLine("Your guess is too high, next guess: {0}", guess);
        }
        else
        {
            start = guess;
            Console.WriteLine("Your guess is too low, guess again: {0}", guess);
        }
        count = count + 1;
        Console.WriteLine("Count {0}", count);
    }
}
```

Comment: That's just saying "if it enters the loop, subtract 1".  It's not really a solution as it is a band-aid.

Comment: @KyleW I've no idea what you mean.  I added an if statement to his original code to make it work correctly

Comment: I'm saying that you fixed this particular issue by treating the symptom, not the cause.

Comment: @KyleW interesting point of view -- I added 3 lines to the code and fixed the program.  This should make it clear where his logic was wrong and I expect help him to understand problem solving better in the future.  The goal was not to re-write program but to solve the problem.  Since the real cause is he is a worse programmer than we are since he is a beginner.

Answer (score -2):

`count` should be `0` to start with not `1`.